# JPA/Hibernate - How is subclass type determined when querying by superclass?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I just noticed this bevahior in Hibernate and found it a bit surprising (in a welcome kind of way).  I have a single entity type called `SyncItem` that serves as a superclass to a number of other entities.  The inheritance strategy is set to `InheritanceType.JOINED` so there is a single table for all the fields in the superclass, and subclass tables just include fields for anything that is added in the subclass, plus a reference back to the superclass table.

So for instance, my `SyncItem` table looks like:

```
mysql> describe syncItems;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| hidden     | bit(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| createDate | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modifyDate | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleteDate | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And if I have a `Property` subclass, it might get a table like:

```
mysql> describe properties;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| syncId       | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| propertyCode | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now I've got about a dozen different subclasses, and the thing that surprised me is that I have a query like:

```
@NamedQuery(
    name="SyncItem.findByTitle", 
    query="SELECT s FROM SyncItem s WHERE s.title = :title")
```

When I wrote this, I expected that because I am selecting from `SyncItem`, I would only get back the information contained in the superclass table (i.e. that I would get a `SyncItem` instance, and not a `Property` instance).  When I ran it, however, I found that the query actually returns the proper subclass instance.  This is good, because it makes a number of things easier to implement.

However, I'm wondering, how is JPA/Hibernate managing to bring back the subclass?  It has no way of knowing that a given title will map to a `Property` and not to something else, and as far as I can tell it has no direct mapping from `syncItems` to `properties` (instead it has to map back from `properties` to `syncItems`).  Is it doing a join with every single subclass table when this query executes?  If so then doesn't that make the query very expensive?

So yeah, just wondering what is going on behind the scenes here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it performs a Join for every sub-table. It is expensive, but you can use any of the other 2 strategies to map inheritance.

[Here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html#jpa_overview_mapping_inher_joined_disadv) you can find a reference where this is stated:

> the joined strategy is often the slowest of the inheritance models.
>   Retrieving any subclass requires one or more database joins, and
>   storing subclasses requires multiple INSERT or UPDATE statements

Each one of the 3 available strategies has its own advantages and disadvantages (if you prefer to save space instead of time, or a compromise between both). The choice depends also on the kind of operations you are going to perform on these tables more often. In the reference I pasted you will find a fairly good and simple explanation of each one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it joins all subclasses. It is probably more expensive than no join but not as much since keys are indexed and only one table will contain required key. Using inheritance will inevitably have some overhead.

You can look at SQL log output to see for yourself.